# Does this argument about basis vectors from what we know about the rank of the matrix make sense?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix $X$ with column vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ (It only have 3 columns). If we find that the rank of the matrix is exactly 3, can we argue that $v1, v2, v3$ does indeed form a basis in the column space of $X$ since they must be linear independent?

Comment: If the rank equals the number of columns, the columns have no choice but to be a basis of the column space. They are always a generating set, and a generating set whose (finite!) cardinality equals the dimension is a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, In fact we know the maximum dimension of the column space is 3 since it is a map from a 3-dimensional vector space to a 3 dimensional vector space. Therefore any 3 linearly independent vectors will be a basis for the column space.